# Google Cloud VM instance not listening on port 443

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, port-443

In the settings for the Virtual Machine (Debian), I selected "allow https traffic".
After installing Apache2, I tried to access the web server through https but it doesn't work.

What needs to be done to allow 443?
Do I need to create a certificate by myself or is this all supposed to be automated?

This is the result of `nmap localhost` showing 443 working, but 443 doesn't work on Apache:

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
22/tcp  open  ssh
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

Comment: It sounds like the problem might be at the application level, not the network level.  In what way does HTTPS not work?  Is the connection timing out, coming back with a bad response code, giving you certificate errors?

Comment: It turned out it was a certificate problem, I used a self signed certificate, which major browsers dont like. I'll be using this server for iOS receipt validation. Will this work with my self signed certificate?

Comment: I highly doubt that iOS will be happy with a self-signed certificate.  Fortunately, it's pretty easy these days to get a free certificate from somebody like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/).  Their software (Certbot) even has an Apache plugin.